# swing create a customized Jbutton issue

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, custom-component

I would like to create my own custom buttons with a defined size and a defined color.
For this purpose I used the Custom Component creating a class that extend a JButton.
Unfortunately I realized that when I override `paintComponent()` and call `super.paintComponent(g)` at the end of the method, it cause the overriding of the color setting made. However, if I don't call the super method, the button does not have the clickable functionality anymore.

Any suggestion if there is anything wrong in my code, or something missing? Any advise for achieve my goal?

Comment: "However, if I don't call the super method, the button does not have the clickable functionality anymore" Can you be more specific about that? What exactly do you mean by that? And why would you call super.paintComponent() at the **end** of your method? Note that you can just call various set functions to specify custom colors, no need to extend JButton.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: *"..does not have the clickable functionality anymore"* It probably does but is simply not *displaying* focus and activation (presses).  In any case for this I'd tend to use an undecorated button, with two or more icons of each base color, the set comprising 'normal icon', 'focused icon', 'pressed icon' etc..  Much simpler than extending button.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CreateRoundButton extends JButton {
  public CreateRoundButton(String label) {
    super(label);
    Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
    size.width = size.height = Math.max(size.width,size.height);
    setPreferredSize(size);
    //added to remove a border of the text in jbutton
    setFocusPainted(false);
    setContentAreaFilled(false);
  }

  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (getModel().isArmed()) {
      g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
    } else {
      g.setColor(getBackground());
    }
    g.fillOval(0, 0, getSize().width-1,getSize().height-1);

    super.paintComponent(g);
  }

  protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(getForeground());
    g.drawOval(0, 0, getSize().width-1,     getSize().height-1);
  }

  Shape shape;
  public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
    if (shape == null || 
      !shape.getBounds().equals(getBounds())) {
      shape = new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    return shape.contains(x, y);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JButton button = new CreateRoundButton("Click");
    button.setBackground(Color.gray);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setSize(150, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Taken from here http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/swing/createRoundButton.html

Comment: not then text isn't visible, super.paintComponent(g) should be last code line for custom painting (just an only) for JButton

Answer (score 0):

I tried as well in this way, but putting the calling to the super method in the beginning cause that the text button is not visibile any more! 
Actually in both case I call the super method the properties that I setted has been overridden.

My goal si change size, shape and color of the button kipping all other Jbutton proteries.
Here my code.

```
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
       if (getModel().isArmed()) {
          g2d.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
       } else {
          g2d.setColor(this.colorwell);
       }
        g2d.fillOval(0, 0, getSize().width-1,getSize().height-1);
        g.dispose();
      }

      protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(getForeground());
        g.drawOval(0, 0, getSize().width-1,     getSize().height-1);
      }
```